# Show that the finite product of compact (or connected) spaces are compact (or connected) without homeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, connectedness

I know this question has been asked many times before. The problem is, every answer I have found so far invokes homeomorphisms. My class has not discussed these, and my professor said this problem is possible without homeomorphisms.

Is anyone able to shine some light on how I'd do this without homeomorphisms?

And if possible, I'd also like a brief explanation of what a homeomorphism is for my future.

To write it here, the two problems are:

Show that the finite product of compact spaces are compact.

Show that the finite product of connected spaces are connected.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the context ? Normed space ? Metric spaces ? Topological spaces ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem? Also, here you can read about homeomorphis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism.

Comment: No context was given. This is the only wording I was told. For the next comment, I do not have an attempt. I was googling to try to find something to get me started. However, all of them have to do with homeomorphisms, so I wasn't able to get started. I am unsure of how to begin.

Comment: @DominicBlanco But in which context have you been introduced to compact spaces ? Is your lesson about normed, metric or topological spaces ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ah I see what you mean. We have done metric and topological spaces. I've seen both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's enough to show the product of 2 compact spaces is compact, and the general case is given by induction.

Let $X,Y$ be compact. Note that for any $y\in Y$ the map $i_{y} : X \rightarrow X \times Y$ given by $i_{y} (x) = (x,y)$ is continuous, and so its' image - $X \times \{y\}$  - is compact as the continuous image of a compact space, for any $y \in Y$. The same argument shows $\{x\} \times Y$ is compact for any choice of $x \in X$. Let $\{ u_{\alpha} \}$ be an open cover of $X \times Y$. For any $y \in Y$, this is also an open cover of $X \times \{y\}$ so it admits a finite subcover $u_{\alpha_{1}} (y), ... , u_{\alpha_{n(y)}} (y)$. Let $U(y) = \cup_{i=1}^{n(y)} u_{\alpha_{i}} (y)$. Note that the set $\{ U(y) | y \in Y$ is an open cover of $ \{x\} times Y$ for arbitrary choice of $x \in X$, so it admits a finite subcover, $U(y_{1}), ... , U(y_{m})$. It is now easy to verify that $\{ u_{\alpha_{k}}(y_{j}) | 1\leq j \leq m, 1 \leq m \leq j(y) \}$ is a finite subcover of $X \times Y$.

Comment: Hey there. This seems to make sense. I do have one question though, more of a clarification question. When you do X x {y}, what does that mean? I get X x Y, it's like a cross product of spaces I'd think. But when you do a space times an element, what is that significance? What's the difference between that and a union of that space and the element?

Comment: $X \times \{y\} = \{ (x,y) | x \in X \} \subseteq X \times Y $, with the subset topology

Comment: So it's any point (x,y) where x is in X, and y is arbitrary? If so then that makes sense.